# Should I use a column both as distkey and sortkey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift containing billion records ( log file entries ). It has a timestamp column ts on which I have distkey and sortkey. Following query:

```
 select ts from apilogs where date(ts) = '2016-09-08'  limit 10;
```

runs super fast when I query for old date; but not for latest date ! Not sure why ! Any help is appreciated

How I put logs: I had put all old log files in one shot into this table; while every incremental log files I put hourly.

When I checked detailed plan on AWS console; I can see that query taking long time is scanning all billion rows; while query taking few milliseconds is scanning only few thousands of rows ( i.e. rows corresponding to that date )..

So, now question is why it is scanning whole table for latest timestamp !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dist key and sort key can be on the same column. No Problem!
Your latest data load in your log table, was it sorted according to the sort key? If not, you will have to run vacuum on your log table, so that your sort key column is sorted in that order and redshift does not have to scan unnecessary rows.
Run the below query to check if you have any unsorted region in your table.
`select trim(pgdb.datname) as Database,
    trim(a.name) as Table,  ((b.mbytes/part.total::decimal)*100)::decimal(5,2) as pct_of_total, b.mbytes, b.unsorted_mbytes, (unsorted_mbytes/mbytes::decimal)*100 as unsorted_pct
    from stv_tbl_perm a
    join pg_database as pgdb on pgdb.oid = a.db_id
    join (select tbl, sum(decode(unsorted, 1, 1, 0)) as unsorted_mbytes, count(*) as mbytes
    from stv_blocklist group by tbl) b on a.id=b.tbl
    join ( select sum(capacity) as  total
      from stv_partitions where part_begin=0 ) as part on 1=1
    where a.slice=0 and a.name in ('apilogs')
    order by 3 desc, db_id, name;` 
 
If you have unsorted region, run
`Vacuum apilogs to 100 percent`

Comment: Yes I am querying on timestamp; and timestamp is distkey and sortkey

Comment: Declaring sort key wont sort your data. You have to load your data in sorted order and if it not loaded in sorted order, you have to run vacuum to sort and merge your data.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you haven't run `vacuum` on your table, after you added rows for latest timestamp.

Here's the part, most relevant to your use case, from the Redshift [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Reclaiming_storage_space202.html?shortFooter=true):

> When data is initially loaded into a table that has a sort key, the data is sorted according to the SORTKEY specification in the CREATE TABLE statement. However, when you update the table, using COPY, INSERT, or UPDATE statements, new rows are stored in a separate unsorted region on disk, then sorted on demand for queries as required. If large numbers of rows remain unsorted on disk, query performance might be degraded for operations that rely on sorted data, such as range-restricted scans or merge joins. The VACUUM command merges new rows with existing sorted rows, so range-restricted scans are more efficient and the execution engine doesn't need to sort rows on demand during query execution.

P.S.- You shouldn't be worried about your distribution key here, as they come into picture only during joins.

Comment: If I run vacum; then all data till that date runs fast.. but any data after that still is slow... I insert logs hourly.. So how frequently should I run vacum ! Also, is there a way to run vacum only on my latest set of data

Comment: 'is there a way to run vacum only on my latest set of data'- no

Comment: 'how frequently should I run vacum'- as frequently as your data changes, probably after every time you insert new logs.

Comment: thanks for your inputs... but dont you think that would be overkill .. to run vacum on billion rows when inserting tens of thousands of records.. running vacum on this table takes atleast 24 hrs